# JS Problems by working with multiple fetched MySQL data [PHP, MySQL & JS]

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm learning JS and have some problems with my script and need your help!

I'm working on a code where I have a list of fetched img title from my database and by clicking on a title, there should popup a div box with a description.

**My problem is, that my script code works only with the 1st fetched data.**

Here is the simple version of my code:
**and below the code i created a snipped (without php elements)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>XY</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="frame">
        <?php
        $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "xy");
        $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM images");
          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
          {
            echo "<div class='A'>";
              echo "<a class='img_id'># ".$row['img_id']."</a><br>";
              echo "<div id='img_title'><a>Title: <b>".$row['img_title']."</b></a></div>";
            echo "</div>";
          }
          echo "<div id='popup'>";

          echo "</div>";
        ?>
    </div>

    <style>
      *{font-family: arial; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;}
      body{background-color:rgba(100,100,100);}
      .A{height: 50px; width: 150px; background-color:rgba(150,150,150); margin-bottom: 10px; margin-left: 10px;}
      .img_id{color:rgba(100,100,100);}
      #img_title{color: white;} #img_title:hover{cursor: pointer; color:rgba(50,50,50);}
      #popup{position: absolute; height: 300px; width: 500px; top: 0px; left: 170px; background-color:rgba(50,50,50); opacity: 0;}
    </style>

    <script>
    document.getElementById('img_title').onclick = function()
    {
      var bg = document.getElementById('popup');
      bg.setAttribute("style", "opacity: 1;");
    }
    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

#### **SNIPPET BELOW WITHOUT PHP ELEMENTS**

```js
document.getElementById('img_title').onclick = function()
{
  var bg = document.getElementById('popup');
  bg.setAttribute("style", "opacity: 0;");
  bg.setAttribute("style", "opacity: 1;");
}
```

```css
*{
font-family: arial; 
padding: 0px; 
margin: 0px;
}

body{
background-color:rgba(100,100,100);
}

.A{
height: 50px; 
width: 150px; 
background-color:rgba(150,150,150); 
margin-bottom: 10px; 
margin-left: 10px;
}

.img_id{
color:rgba(100,100,100);
}
       
#img_title{
color: white;
}

#img_title:hover{
cursor: pointer; 
color:rgba(50,50,50);
}

#popup{
position: absolute; 
height: 300px; 
width: 500px; 
top: 0px; 
left: 170px; 
background-color:rgba(50,50,50); 
opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>XY</title>
       <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
      </head>

      <body>
        <div id="frame">
            <div class='A'>
              <a class='img_id'>#1</a><br>
              <div id='img_title'><a>Title: AAAAA<b></b></a></div>
            </div>
            
             <div class='A'>
              <a class='img_id'>#2</a><br>
              <div id='img_title'><a>Title: BBBBB<b></b></a></div>
            </div>

             <div class='A'>
              <a class='img_id'>#3</a><br>
              <div id='img_title'><a>Title: CCCCC<b></b></a></div>
            </div>

            <div id='popup'>
            </div>
        </div>
      </body>

    </html>
```

**Only #1 do work (you have to refresh and click on #2, to see, it doesn't work)**

Later i want to fetch the image description in this popup box, but this is not part of this question!

Comment: Id's should be unique `img_title` should be a class.

Comment: i used a class instead and "getElementsByClassName" instead of "getElementById", but then nothing works, no idea why

Comment: I'm not much of a JS'er PHP/mysql brought me. `getElementsByClassName` I'd think will give you back an array of all classes. What about using inline `onclick`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I've changed `id='img_title'`to `class='img_title'`since you can't have more than 1 id with the same name.
2. In javaScript I've putted `.img_title` elements in an array (`myarray`). You can iterate the array using the method `map()`for example but you may chose to use other method.

```js
let myarray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.img_title'))
let bg = document.getElementById('popup');
myarray.map((e) => {
e.addEventListener("click", e=>{
  bg.setAttribute("style", "opacity: 0;");
  bg.setAttribute("style", "opacity: 1;");
})
})
```

```css
*{
font-family: arial; 
padding: 0px; 
margin: 0px;
}

body{
background-color:rgba(100,100,100);
}

.A{
height: 50px; 
width: 150px; 
background-color:rgba(150,150,150); 
margin-bottom: 10px; 
margin-left: 10px;
}

.img_id{
color:rgba(100,100,100);
}
       
#img_title{
color: white;
}

#img_title:hover{
cursor: pointer; 
color:rgba(50,50,50);
}

#popup{
position: absolute; 
height: 300px; 
width: 500px; 
top: 0px; 
left: 170px; 
background-color:rgba(50,50,50); 
opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
        <div id="frame">
            <div class='A'>
              <a class='img_id'>#1</a><br>
              <div class='img_title'><a>Title: AAAAA<b></b></a></div>
            </div>
            
             <div class='A'>
              <a class='img_id'>#2</a><br>
              <div class='img_title'><a>Title: BBBBB<b></b></a></div>
            </div>

             <div class='A'>
              <a class='img_id'>#3</a><br>
              <div class='img_title'><a>Title: CCCCC<b></b></a></div>
            </div>

            <div id='popup'>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I hope it helps

UPDATE

I would need to know more about what you need. I'm not very sure this will do. Please try this in your JavaScript:

```js
let myarray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.img_title'))
let bg = document.getElementById('popup');
myarray.map((e) => {
e.addEventListener("click", e=>{
  // retrieve the actual value of opacity for bg
  bgStyle = window.getComputedStyle(bg, null).getPropertyValue("opacity");
  // if the opacity is "0" make it "1" otherwhise make it "0"
  let opacity = bgStyle == "0" ? "1" : 0;
  // use the opacity variable
  bg.setAttribute("style", `opacity:${opacity};`); 
})
})
```

Comment: a other question, do you know how to uncheck/reverse by clicking on the title again?

Comment: your update works also very well! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The ID element should not be repeated.

Use jQuery click listener on class:

```
$( ".img_id" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

Comment: I testet out the class instead of a id before, but then nothing work. I want to leran js before i use any js library but thanks for your answer anyway

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the same id (img_title) multiple times..

The id attribute has to be unique in the page.

Use classes to do that and you are correct

Comment: i used a class instead of a id and "getElementsByClassName" instead of "getElementById", but then nothing works, no idea why

Comment: Use `addEventListener` function instead of `onclick= function`

Comment: and what is the reason, why onclick would'nt work? (i'm new to js and want learn)

Comment: And also you have to bind the events in body.onLoad event to work correctly.